Make equation counter follows customized counter
Objective
Hi. I define a counter, say, no for my customized commands, such as
\newcounter{no}
\counterwithin{no}{chapter}
\newcommand{\no}{\refstepcounter{no}%
                 \theno}
\newcommand{\df}{\normalfont{\textbf{Definition \no}}\;}

Now I would like the equation counter (\theequation) follows the customized counter \thno.
How I use customized counter and what I expect
For example,
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] \df This is some definition.
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
some equation.
\end{equation}

I expect the result would be
Definition 1.1 This is some definition.

                                    some equation.                                 (1.2)

What I've tried

I've tried
\let\theequation\theno

but \theequation does not update in equation environment; the temporary remedy for using equation environment is
\addtocounter{no}{1}   % update the counter
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}

but that is annoying.

Since the customized counter no is NOT used for new environment, remedy using \newtheorem does not fit for me.

I've tried
\let\theequation\theno
\renewenvironment{equation}{\refstepcounter{no}\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}

or
\renewenvironment{equation}{\refstepcounter{no}\begin{equation}}{\tag{\theno}\end{equation}}

but they all give the error message: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=200000].



By the way, I also wish that the counter of align can follow the customized counter no so that the numbering of no, equation, and algin are consecutive.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

You just want to use equation.
\documentclass{book}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}

\newcommand{\no}{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}

\newcommand{\df}{\textbf{Definition \no}\enspace\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\df This is some definition.
\begin{equation}
some equation.
\end{equation}

\end{document}

Note that \normalfont is not a command taking an argument like \textbf. Anyway, I'm not sure why not using standard tools such as \newtheorem.

Better code, in my opinion:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}

%\newcommand{\no}{\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{df}
This is some definition.
\begin{equation}
some equation.
\end{equation}
\end{df}

\end{document}


Is this what you want?

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}
\begin{document}
\chapter{AAAAA}

\begin{definition}
  hello
\end{definition}

\begin{equation}
  a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{definition}
  world
\end{definition}

\begin{equation}
  c=d
\end{equation}

\begin{definition}
  foo
\end{definition}

\begin{align}
  a & = b \\
    & = c
\end{align}
\end{document}


Hi. Thanks for replying. The numbering, yes. But the definition is not in environment.
